# Java: How to call one argument from methods with multiple arguments

Tags: java, android

sorry if my question is stupid, but i have problem with calling variable from method with few arguments.

```
public void onAccelSensorChanged(long axisX, long axisY, long axisZ) {

        accelx = axisX;
        accely = axisY;
        accelz = axisZ;

        accelText.setText("\nACCELEROMETER: \nX: " + axisX + "nm/s^2 || Y: " + axisY + "nm/s^2 || Z: " + axisZ +"nm/s^2");
    }
```

Ok, and i need call variable accelx, accely, accelz, but each of them elsewhere in the code.. Is there any simple method to do this in java?

I need make something like that:

```
case 0xf41f1000: /*pongiGetAccelerateX()*/
            //i need call accelX in below 'pongiGetAccelerateX method, but now it returned 0 
            result = spnNative.pongiGetAccelerateX(accelX);

            break;
```

------EDIT----

My class :

```
public class SPN_API implements onAccelSensorChanged{

    private SPN_native spnNative;
    public long accelX, accelY, accelZ;

    public SPN_API() {
        spnNative = new SPN_native();

    }

    public byte[] invoke_command(int commandId, int argsImageLength, int actualNrOfArgs) {
        byte[] result = null;
        switch(commandId){

        case 0xf41f1000: /*pongiGetAccelerateX()*/
            //i need call accelX in below 'pongiGetAccelerateX method, but now it returned 0 
            result = spnNative.pongiGetAccelerateX(accelX);
            break;
        case 0xf51f1000: /*pongiGetAccelerateY()*/
            result = spnNative.pongiGetAccelerateX(accelY);
            break;
        case 0xf61f1000: /*pongiGetAccelerateZ()*/
            result = spnNative.pongiGetAccelerateX(accelZ);
            break;

        }
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAccelSensorChanged(long axisX, long axisY, long axisZ) {

            accelx = axisX;
            accely = axisY;
            accelz = axisZ;     
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are they in the code? Same class or some other class? Please enter the code where these variables are declared and relation between two classes(if seperate)

Answer (score 0):

You can either return the value and pass it into the other function as an argument or you can use a global variable in the class scope so that it can be accessed and changed from anywhere.

Comment: I added full of code of my class. Maybe now you can help me. :)

Comment: You know, they're globally defined within the class, so all methods can access them.

Comment: When i make log.d("show accelX", " " + accelX);  before for example  result = spnNative.pongiGetAccelerateX(accelX); - it always show 0, so 0 is transferred to pongiGetAccelerateX and my whole project doesn't work

Comment: If it's zero, then you `onAccelSensorChange` doesn't change the value or initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class `implements SensorEventListener`.

Then remove `onAccelSensorChange` and copy this in.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        accelX = event.values[0];
        accelY = event.values[1];
        accelZ = event.values[2];
    }
}
```